# Console log not running

Tags: javascript, reactjs

i try to console log the event but it does not show up in my Console .

```
const Map =({ setCoordinates,setBounds,coordinates})=>{

    const classes = useStyles();
    const isMobile = useMediaQuery('(min-width:600px)');

    return (
        <div className ={classes.mapContainer}>
            <GoogleMapReact
             bootstrapURLKeys={{key:'AIzaSyBzm5Anh5jLzGKAY8Vg_bUqVQ8CITHim8o'}}
             defaultCenter={coordinates}
             center={coordinates}
             defaultZoom={14}
             margin={[50,50,50,50]}
             options={''}
             onClick={(e)=>{
               console.log(e);  

                setCoordinates({lat:e.center.lat, lng:e.center.lng});
              
               }}
            // onChildClick={''}
        >

            </GoogleMapReact>
        </div>
    );
   
}
```

not sure where is the problem is hmmmm it does not run the code inside the `<GoogleMapReact>`

Comment: You are trying to console log `e`. What do you expect gets logged?

Comment: @DSteman - I'd say it's the `event` argument to onclick, which is `e` in the code

Comment: @JaromandaX removing a syntactically correct comment obviously doesn't affect anything.

Comment: It's JSX not markup. That comment is valid.

Comment: Try to console log any string just to see is onClick firing.

Comment: can you remove the className attribute in the wrapping div and check ? styles could be interfering with the click behavior

Answer (score 0):

I have tested your code and made a [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/google-map-react-markers-hover-and-click-example-forked-1i913q?file=/src/App.js).

Event is being logged and I have not found any issue.